# Is that possible to have the same behavior of CoFlatMapFunction using other basic operators?

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-edgent

Basically, I am using CoFlatMapFunction (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/co/CoFlatMapFunction.html) to filter a stream and change the filter parameters at runtime and I am using Flink for that. I want to do the same using Apache Edgent TStream (https://edgent.incubator.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/edgent/topology/TStream.html), but it does not have CoFlatMapFunction.
If I use Union it will not work because the streams are different and I am not allowed to do union. If I use Filter I will not have the dynamic behavior that I want.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Flink you can force a Union on streams of different types by using Either. It's a bit hacky, but it seems like it could work with Apache Edgent as well.

Updated:

I'm just learning about Edgent, but it seems to have a notion of control streams: https://edgent.apache.org/recipes/recipe_adaptable_filter_range.html.

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not clear how to do this hacky in Edgent because I cannot find anything similar to `Either` on Apache Edgent (https://edgent.incubator.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/edgent/oplet/core/Union.html)

Comment: The Either monad doesn't depend on Flink. I'm just assuming you can take one of the implementations out there and make it work with Edgent.

Comment: Hi, I could implement the Either approach using Flink-core library (https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-rpi/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sense/edgent/app/TempSensorUnionMqttApp.java). But now I don't know how to implement the union. Do you have any clue? Thanks

Comment: I saw now your update. Thanks. It is working like I asked on my question